# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, entity-framework

Hi it is my first time that I publish a project deveolped with entity framework in a remote server. The pages work fine but when I try to access in my reserved area and so, reading a dabatase, I obtain this error

> Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

**Description**: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

**Exception Details**: System.ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.

Source Error:

An unhandled exception was generated during the execution of the current web request. Information regarding the origin and location of the exception can be identified using the exception stack trace below.

> Stack Trace:
>
> [ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data
>   Provider.  It may not be installed.]
>   System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String
>   providerInvariantName) +1402071
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String
>   providerString) +35
>
> [ArgumentException: The specified store provider cannot be found in
>   the configuration, or is not valid.]
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.GetFactory(String
>   providerString) +62
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection.ChangeConnectionString(String
>   newConnectionString) +263
>   System.Data.EntityClient.EntityConnection..ctor(String
>   connectionString) +81
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext.CreateEntityConnection(String
>   connectionString) +42
>   System.Data.Objects.ObjectContext..ctor(String connectionString,
>   String defaultContainerName) +16
>   shield_trust.db_shieldtrustEntities..ctor() in
>   D:\trust-company\shield_trust\shield_trust\POCO.Context.cs:23
>   shield_trust.user_login.check_login() in
>   D:\trust-company\shield_trust\shield_trust\user_login.aspx.cs:65
>   shield_trust.user_login.entraButton_Click(Object sender, EventArgs e)
>   in D:\trust-company\shield_trust\shield_trust\user_login.aspx.cs:25
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.OnClick(EventArgs e) +118
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +112
>   System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button.System.Web.UI.IPostBackEventHandler.RaisePostBackEvent(String
>   eventArgument) +10
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(IPostBackEventHandler
>   sourceControl, String eventArgument) +13
>   System.Web.UI.Page.RaisePostBackEvent(NameValueCollection postData)
>   +36    System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint)
>   +5563

I have to copy some dll into my bin folder or modify my web.config?

Comment: Check this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32416021/ado-net-provider-with-invariant-name-system-data-sqlclient-cannot-be-found-e/32416819), it worked for me just now!

Answer (score 17):

Try running this to get a list of installed providers, and check yours is there:

```
// This example assumes a reference to System.Data.Common.
static DataTable GetProviderFactoryClasses()
{
    // Retrieve the installed providers and factories.
    DataTable table = DbProviderFactories.GetFactoryClasses();

    // Display each row and column value.
    foreach (DataRow row in table.Rows)
    {
        foreach (DataColumn column in table.Columns)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(row[column]);
        }
    }
    return table;
}
```

UPDATE: You need to have the MySQL Provider installed on the target machine, it's called something like "MySQL Connector Net x.x.x" Which you can get from [this website](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/net/6.8.html)

Update 09/06/2022: As this is still looked at for an answer I thought I would just point out that Nuget packages are almost an industry standard, and as such, for newer non-legacy applications I would recommend looking at the MySqlConnector Nuget package which is currently supported, and had an update as recently as 6/5/2022, See [mysqlconnector.net](https://mysqlconnector.net/) for more information.

Comment: but the machine is a remote machine in hosting and I can't install nothing. I try to copy the MySql.Data.dll, the MySql.Data.Entity.dll and MySql.Web.dll files into my bin remote folder but I doesn't work

Comment: You copied them to your bin, but have you referenced them in your project ?

Comment: no, I have not referenced in my project because I did not know I had to. When I uploaded this work to another machine everything worked without doing anything. The problem I had with this new hosting

Comment: The other machine probably has mysql connector on it... add the references to the DLLs and try again.

Comment: to add a reference to the "right button" project name -> reference path -> folder and I add the 3 dll?

Comment: Right click reference folder (inside the project) and select Add Reference then browse and add the 3 DLLs

Comment: I referenced the dll but it doesn't work. It's possibile that the only way is install the connector on the machine?

Comment: Yes it is possible that they must be in the GAC on the target machine. Although connector net 6.6 release notes say "enhancements to partial trust support to allow hosting services to deploy applications without installing the Connector/Net library in the GAC"

Comment: Try running the code above on the target machine, the target machine might have an older one installed, worth checking out.

Comment: I did it before, and I noticed that the target machine hasn't installed the .Net Framework Data Provider for MySql

Comment: But they do have a MySQL database?

Comment: Yes they have a MySQL database and now they have installed the connector. It works

Comment: Do not install any connector globally. 1st reason: it requires an installation which may be impossible if we use a shared server. 2nd reason: it reduces the flexibility of using different versions on different projects. The error in the question occurred because the project wasn't configured right; udog's answer will fix the issue.

Comment: @Quan Maybe you could provide a download link to the DLL? or did you have to install the connector to get it? P.S. If you have one MySql DB and want to use different versions of the connector... erm far out man and good luck... if you use a shared environment which utilises MySql and has .Net available then I suspect there is a high probability that the .Net Connector will already be installed... sounds a bit like the beginnings of a maintenance headache for you.

Comment: @PaulZahra, I installed the connector globally and locally on my development laptop version A. Then, I added reference and set "Copy to Local" in Visual Studio. If the connector version A was installed on the server then no problem. But if version B was installed I would have a trouble. If no connector is installed, then the server will use the ones in bin folder of specific projects. That's why I suggested we shouldn't install any connector on the server and let that responsibility to project configuration.

Comment: @Quan There can be security issues with regards to what trust level the application has compared to which trust levels mysql connector requires, installing it in the GAC can provide a separation of concerns and allow the app to run differently to the GAC version, also the bin version can override the GAC version.

Answer (score 11):

With our applications (ASP.NET, Test, Windows Service), we've had to add the below to our app.config or web.config files (inside the `configuration` node) to make this work:

```
<system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <remove invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
            <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```

Comment: I uninstalled .NET connector (whatever version) from Windows Control Panel. Then, I put this config into my web.config and run the website again, it fixed. Thanks! The reason it works is that, I force IIS to use my dll in bin folder and do not use anywhere else library (actually there is no where else because I already uninstalled the connector from my machine, the only things left are the dll in the web app bin folder.

Answer (score 7):

If you receive a dialog as follows...

"Unable to Find the Requested .NET Framework Data Provider. It may Not be Installed"

Look in the machine.config files in the following locations…

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config
```

Remove any empty

```
"DbProviderFactories" nodes.
```

Comment: It works for me: I commented out the DbProviderFactories in: C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config\machine.config

Answer (score 4):

For us it was 32 vs. 64 bit process.
The server is 64 bit.
The ODP.NET (Oracle Client) installed is also 64 bit.
Our application compiled with the Target platform "Any CPU" and "Prefer 32-bit" flag SET:

http://grab.by/v5ki

was running as 32 bit process.
Once recompiled with the flag un-checked everything started to work.

Answer (score 3):

I know this is old but as explained by **udog** this section of the error message "The specified store provider cannot be found in the configuration, or is not valid" indicates what the issue is. So depending on the backend database add the provider information to the config file. If already added make sure it is correct. For oracle if using the managed provider for EF and oracle.DataAccess it will look something like this. Note your oracle dll version might be different.

```
<system.data>
   <DbProviderFactories>
       <remove invariant="Oracle.MaanagedDataAccess.Client"/>
       <add name="ODP.NET, Managed Driver" invariant="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET, Managed Driver" type="Oracle.ManagedDataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.ManagedDataAccess, Version=4.121.2.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>  
   <add name="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" invariant="Oracle.DataAccess.Client" description="Oracle Data Provider for .NET" type="Oracle.DataAccess.Client.OracleClientFactory, Oracle.DataAccess, Version=4.112.3.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=89b483f429c47342"/>
   </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Comment: I'm actually using Oracle, so this is just what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Embarrassingly, I spent three days trying to solve this error. I had an incorrect "providerName" property on my "connectionString"

Changed from:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Old" connectionString="Server=servername;Database=databasename;Uid=userid;Pwd=password;" providerName="System.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

to:

```
<configuration>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="Old" connectionString="Server=servername;Database=databasename;Uid=userid;Pwd=password;" providerName="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

I had specified `System.Data.MySqlClient` instead of `Mysql.Data.MySqlClient`

d'oh!

Comment: To anyone who is concerned, check for typos (even if it's already in version control). Thanks for the tip.

Answer (score 1):

When connecting to a database a so called 'data provider' is used for the abstraction of implementations.

Your exception seems to say that the given dataprovider is not present on the target machine. Which database do you use in your deployed environment? Check your web.config connectionstring for specifics.

You might have to install the given dataprovider yourself on that machine (one time) so it is available from the Global Assembly Cache (GAC).

Comment: I use a MySql database

Answer (score 1):

The  statement added to  in Web.config helped me.

```
<system.data>
        <DbProviderFactories>
            <clear />
            <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
        </DbProviderFactories>
    </system.data>
```

Answer (score 0):

To build further on udog's answer, if you are going to have multiple applications on the server using this data provider, then it probably makes more sense to add it to the machine.config file.

As Thomas notes, the machine.config files are located here:

> C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v4.0.30319\Config
>   C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\Config

The machine.config entry is like the web.config entry:

```
<system.data>
    <DbProviderFactories>
        <add name="MySQL Data Provider" invariant="MySql.Data.MySqlClient" description=".Net Framework Data Provider for MySQL" type="MySql.Data.MySqlClient.MySqlClientFactory, MySql.Data, Version=6.5.4.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=c5687fc88969c44d" />
    </DbProviderFactories>
</system.data>
```

Note: If you have your application on multiple servers (e.g. QA/test server and a production server) and you are only getting this error on one of them, I would recommend doing a file dif between the machine.config files to see if there is a difference between the servers.

Answer (score 0):

I ran into same error while I was trying to install a stand alone tools on my personal PC. I did the following steps.NET framework 2.0 and 3.0).NET Framework 4.7 Advanced services was re installed but doesn't fix the problem, before I finally used this simple fix procedure.
Download and install SSCERuntime_x64-ENU.exe 
Follow this link to download https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=30709
Good luck.