# Nhibernate - C# Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider. It may not be installed

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, iis, nhibernate

[image: error throw]

When I migrated from PC to another fresh PC I got this error. Can anyone help me?

*I'm using Nhibernate, ASP.NET MVC

```
Unable to find the requested .Net Framework Data Provider.  It may not
be installed. [ArgumentException: Unable to find the requested .Net
Framework Data Provider.  It may not be installed.]   
System.Data.Common.DbProviderFactories.GetFactory(String
providerInvariantName) +1279138   
NHibernate.Driver.ReflectionBasedDriver..ctor(String
providerInvariantName, String driverAssemblyName, String
connectionTypeName, String commandTypeName) +196   
NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver..ctor() +66

[TargetInvocationException: Exception has been thrown by the target of
an invocation.]    System.RuntimeTypeHandle.CreateInstance(RuntimeType
type, Boolean publicOnly, Boolean noCheck, Boolean& canBeCached,
RuntimeMethodHandleInternal& ctor, Boolean& bNeedSecurityCheck) +0   
System.RuntimeType.CreateInstanceSlow(Boolean publicOnly, Boolean
skipCheckThis, Boolean fillCache, StackCrawlMark& stackMark) +138   
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type, Boolean nonPublic) +105   
System.Activator.CreateInstance(Type type) +12   
NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2
settings) +180

[HibernateException: Could not create the driver from
NHibernate.Driver.MySqlDataDriver.]   
NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProvider.ConfigureDriver(IDictionary`2
settings) +429   

NHibernate.Connection.ConnectionProviderFactory.NewConnectionProvider(IDictionary`2
settings) +467   
NHibernate.Cfg.SettingsFactory.BuildSettings(IDictionary`2 properties)
+985    NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSettings() +30    NHibernate.Cfg.Configuration.BuildSessionFactory() +50   
gta.app.web.NHibernateSession.OpenSession(List`1 psHBMList) in

d:\Project\lianhuat\gta.app.web\Models\NHibernate\NHibernateSession.cs:22
gta.app.web.Controllers.SystemController.getT9010ById(String Password)
in d:\Project\lianhuat\gta.app.web\Controllers\SystemController.cs:965
gta.app.web.Controllers.SystemController.Login(DataSourceRequest
poRequest, String kdpUserID, String kdpPassword) in
d:\Project\lianhuat\gta.app.web\Controllers\SystemController.cs:980   
lambda_method(Closure , ControllerBase , Object[] ) +238   
System.Web.Mvc.ReflectedActionDescriptor.Execute(ControllerContext
controllerContext, IDictionary`2 parameters) +229   

System.Web.Mvc.ControllerActionInvoker.InvokeActionMethod(ControllerContext
controllerContext, ActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, IDictionary`2
parameters) +35   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.<BeginInvokeSynchronousActionMethod>b__36(IAsyncResult
asyncResult, ActionInvocation innerInvokeState) +39   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncResult`2.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +67   

System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethod(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +42   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncInvocationWithFilters.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3c()
+72    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass45.<InvokeActionMethodFilterAsynchronouslyRecursive>b__3e()
+386    System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeActionMethodWithFilters(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +42   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass28.<BeginInvokeAction>b__19()
+38    System.Web.Mvc.Async.<>c__DisplayClass1e.<BeginInvokeAction>b__1b(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +186   

System.Web.Mvc.Async.AsyncControllerActionInvoker.EndInvokeAction(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +38   
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.<BeginExecuteCore>b__1d(IAsyncResult
asyncResult, ExecuteCoreState innerState) +29   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +65   
System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecuteCore(IAsyncResult asyncResult) +53
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +36    System.Web.Mvc.Controller.EndExecute(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +38   
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.<BeginProcessRequest>b__4(IAsyncResult
asyncResult, ProcessRequestState innerState) +44   
System.Web.Mvc.Async.WrappedAsyncVoid`1.CallEndDelegate(IAsyncResult
asyncResult) +65   
System.Web.Mvc.MvcHandler.EndProcessRequest(IAsyncResult asyncResult)
+38    System.Web.CallHandlerExecutionStep.System.Web.HttpApplication.IExecutionStep.Execute()
+657    System.Web.HttpApplication.ExecuteStep(IExecutionStep step, Boolean& completedSynchronously) +146
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i got the answer, the problem solved after i already installed mysql connector .net. thanks anyone

Answer (score 0):

I am pretty sure that error means that the value of the `providerName` attribute on the connection string in your `web.config` is either incorrect, or the provider literally is not installed.

I am guessing you will just have to install the correct provider. Check references in project to see if any missing dll's etc. Maybe there is dll not installed in GAC on new PC?

Edit: looking at answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21157069/unable-to-find-the-requested-net-framework-data-provider-it-may-not-be-install), I think you will just have to follow these for solution.